# What to do if InputMismatchException keep looping?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create simple Menu for my program. I use InputMismatchException to catch exception when user enter char instead of integer but the program is looping when I enter char.

I left callMenu method empty but I'll fill it after solving this problem.

I am not sure is the mistake in the main menu or in catch part. When I do not write kb.nextInt() in catch section I'm getting infinitive loop. In another case it displayes mistake

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            Menu.showMenu();
            Menu.callMenu(Menu.getChoice());
        } while (true);
    }
}



import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Menu {

    public static void showMenu() {
        System.out.println("----------Menu----------");
        System.out.println("1 - ");
        System.out.println("2 - ");
        System.out.println("0 - Exit");
    }

    public static int getChoice() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n Enter menu number:");
        int choice = kb.nextInt();

        while (!isValidChoice(choice)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("\n INVALID INPUT. Try again.");
                System.out.print("Enter menu number: ");
                choice = kb.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                kb.next();
            } 
        }

        return choice;
    }

    public static boolean isValidChoice(int ch) {
        return ch >= 0 && ch <= 9;
    }

    public static void callMenu(int menuNum) {
        switch (menuNum) {
            case 1:

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 0:
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please try below solution

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to modify your code a lot. Here is what i can see wrong and what i think you can change

1. The point that your are getting the first input will throw an exception if you do not enter a integer. You do not have a catch block around it. So you should take that inside the try catch block to capture any invalid inputs
2. The main method will keep running infinitely when you check the value as "true" in while condition. Change that to false.
3. What i am providing you below assumes that your program will exit if an character/Non-Integer value in entered by displaying an error message.If the inputs are integers, your code will loop until one of your correct menu items are reached
4. I am only putting in the changes and not the whole code below. Rest remains same.

```
public static int getChoice() {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n Enter menu number:");
        int choice=-1;

        try{
            choice = kb.nextInt();
            while (!isValidChoice(choice)) {
                    System.out.println("\n INVALID INPUT. Try again.");
                    System.out.print("Enter menu number: ");
                    choice = kb.nextInt();
            }
        }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        return choice;
    }
```

In your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        Menu.showMenu();
        Menu.callMenu(Menu.getChoice());
        } while (false);
    }
```

Hope this works out. Let me know